# How to mount an USB disk to a fix drive in Linux subsystem for Windows?

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working on Windows-10, where I have installed Linux subsystem for Windows (more exactly a Ubuntu).

I have mapped my USB drive on the D:-drive and Windows believes this to be a general disk:

```
Windows commandline prompt>wmic logicaldisk list (relevant excerpt)
Access  Availability  BlockSize  Caption  Compressed  ConfigManagerErrorCode  ConfigManagerUserConfig  Description         DeviceID  DriveType  ErrorCleared  ErrorDescription  ErrorMethodology  FileSystem  FreeSpace     InstallDate  LastErrorCode  MaximumComponentLength  MediaType  Name  NumberOfBlocks  PNPDeviceID  PowerManagementCapabilities  PowerManagementSupported  ProviderName                                 Purpose  QuotasDisabled  QuotasIncomplete  QuotasRebuilding  Size           Status  StatusInfo  SupportsDiskQuotas  SupportsFileBasedCompression  VolumeName  VolumeSerialNumber
0                                C:       FALSE                                                        Local Fixed Disk    C:        3                                                            NTFS        144074813440                              255                     12         C:                                                                                                                                                                                                  1023013810176                      FALSE               TRUE                          OSDisk      B622B231
0                                D:       FALSE                                                        Local Fixed Disk    D:        3                                                            NTFS        996483739648                              255                     12         D:                                                                                                                                                                                                  1000168484864                      FALSE               TRUE                          Elements    6CD465F5
```

On my Windows PC, I have two extra directories:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\...\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_...\...\rootfs\mnt\c
C:\Users\...\AppData\...\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_...\...\rootfs\mnt\d
```

On my Linux subsystem, `/etc/mtab` finishes as follows:

```
Linux Prompt>tail -n 2 /etc/mtab
C:\134 /mnt/c drvfs rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off 0 0
D:\134 /mnt/d drvfs rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off 0 0
```

Yet, the result of `df -hk` does not show any `/mnt/d`:

```
Linux Prompt>df -hk
df: /mnt/d: Invalid argument
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs         999036924 858339700 140697224  86% /
...
C:\            999036924 858339700 140697224  86% /mnt/c
```

On the internet, I found this command, but it does not give a solution:

```
Linux prompt>mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d
```

And the result of `mount` is quite weird:

```
Linux prompt> sudo mount
rootfs on / type wslfs (rw,noatime)
...
C:\ on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
D:\ on /mnt/d type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
```

Yet, `/mnt/d` does not work: the directory exists, but it's unusable.

Anybody knows what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, just pretend that anything you find under `%AppData%` just doesn't exist.  It's dangerous and its use can cause corruption in WSL ([Microsoft Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)).  I know you probably just came across it by searching in Windows.  Just walk away ... slowly. :-)

*Short answer possible solution:*

Try creating a new mount location:

```
sudo mkdir /media/d
sudo mount -t drvfs D: /media/d
```

Or possibly:

- `wsl --shutdown`
- Reattach the USB drive
- Start the WSL instance

*More detail:*

Here's what I *think* is happening.  WSL reads the Windows attached drives when it is started, and auto-mounts this drive list in each instance (via `/init`) when the instance is started.

If the drive is disconnected after WSL starts, then the subsystem doesn't know about that.  A disconnect and reconnect of the drive (or another drive) will end up in a similar situation to what you are seeing -- A `/mnt/d` (or other drive letter) that doesn't work.

As proposed above, a new mount location (`/media` is nice, since it's normally where you would mount removable drives) or a `wsl --shutdown` and restart resolves the issue for me.