# How to mount a USB flash drive as a Virtual HDD?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, vhd, wsl2, windows-11

The Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 does not currently mount USB flash drives. I'm currently using the Windows 11 Insider Preview with WSL2 kernel version 5.10.43. (It is a known WSL limitation, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#limitations)

However, WSL does mount VHDs located on flash storage, tested it myself. I need to access a partition of a USB flash drive from within WSL. So, is there a way to get over the limitation and mount a flash drive or a partition of a flash drive as a VHD (modify the vhd file to point to a flash drive, or just the flash storage presenting itself as a vhd)?

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  You mention that you can mount VHD's in WSL, but as far as I know that's only available in the Preview/Insider version (and Windows 11 Beta).  Are you using that?  Or perhaps you are referring to using [fuse mounts](https://blog.codybunch.com/2020/10/16/WSL2-Mount-vhdx-to-WSL2/) for this? 
 Probably important to have that tidbit in the question if so to clarify.

Comment: But also, I'm going to flag this as a possible duplicate, since I've already answered a question on how to mount a USB drive in WSL (see [How to mount an USB disk to a fix drive in Linux subsystem for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1666582/how-to-mount-an-usb-disk-to-a-fix-drive-in-linux-subsystem-for-windows)).  If that answers the question, just accept it as a duplicate and close this out.  But if not, let us know and we can delve further.

Comment: Hey, @NotTheDr01ds. Thank you for the suggestion. It just appeared to be a duplicate, I have modified the description to state exactly what the issue is, the last time it was too vague.

Comment: No worries - Thanks for the edit to clarify the use-case.  Yes, accessing a *partition* on a USB drive is definitely different.  I'm still sticking with released Win10 for now, so I haven't had a chance to try out the `--mount` command.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not supported - USB HDD drives are okay, but not USB flash drives. Anyway, if you liked the Windows 7 Aero theme then you're probably going to like Windows 11. I missed the rounded edges :) Just wait for the release, though. If you don't want to wait you can do what I did - upgrade from an iso (from the official Microsoft website).