# Best way to back up an old, probably linux formatted 3.5" boot floppy in 2023?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, floppy

At work we have a very expensive (and older) piece of scientific equipment that for some reason refuses to boot without a floppy disk in it. The tech has advised me the manufacturer probably doesn't have easy access to copies of those floppies anymore, so I'd like to make backups and store them on the department shared drive in case they fail in the future.

I've got some USB floppy drives, and can get an old (probably Windows XP-era) PC with a floppy drive still in it, and some blank floppies I got for testing to make sure I don't accidentally destroy the boot floppy.

[First thing I tried was this method](https://superuser.com/a/664494/1851120), which didn't work since the disk formatting isn't something DOS recognizes.

Then I tried using WSL with Ubuntu. I couldn't find where the drive mounted in ubuntu, so I mounted the drive to `/mnt/a` using `sudo mkdir /mnt/d` followed by `sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d` as outlined on both the [Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/1666674). This lets me access the contents of those disks, but when I try and use `cat` or `dd` to copy the disk I get the messages `Is a directory` or `dd: error reading '/mnt/a': Is a directory`.

Am I mounting the floppy incorrectly, or do I need to get an actual linux computer to do this? Or possibly a non-USB floppy drive?

Edit: To answer some questions: I'm starting with what is fairly obviously a backup of the XRD bootdisk (Label written in sharpie, label is "XRD Bootdisk June 12/13"). It is a Jufifilm MF2HD 1.44MB Double Sided High Density disk, looks quite standard. I'm using the USB Floppy Drive that I found that disk in. (Compaq FD-05PUB, I think.)

The tech who recommended we make backups worked for the manufacturer and has for a long time, so I suspect he would have warned us if they were hard to backup, but I'll reach out to Bruker asking if there is any copy-protection I should worry about, but I doubt is as "Only runs on hundreds of thousands of dollars of equipment that takes a forklift to move" is pretty good protection itself.

To be clear, my main question is "How do I mount this disk in such a way as to be able to cat or dd it? Is this a limitation of WSL or am I just mounting it wrong"?

Comment: A [different answer](https://superuser.com/a/664493/272824) from the one you chose looks to me to be more likely to work. Then you can look into a "floppy drive emulator". The manufacturer would have the best knowledge of whether or not they still have copies. Oh, also, inspect the blank floppies for surface contamination in case they have gone mouldy, and use a floppy drive cleaner to make sure the heads are clean.

Comment: I used that answer for the unix/linux instructions as I would rather use standard tools then a 10 year old 3rd party tool if possible. (I linked it further down in my question)

Comment: 'Security' floppies were formatted in all sorts on non-standard ways, specifically to prevent copying. Your best bet on this is to contact the manufacturer. They ought to know what format & how it could be copied… or may have devised another security method in the intervening years, more compatible with newer systems.

Comment: Did you confirm drive+diskette compatibility? Does the floppy drive support the *density* (e.g. DD, HD or ED) of the boot diskette?  And then there are some oddball 3.5" floppies & drives (mostly used in Japan) that have the same capacity of 8" floppies. BTW adapting instructions for USB flash drive to a floppy may not work. USB flash drives almost always have a partition table in the MBR. The use of floppies predates the MS-DOS partition table, so a floppy should not be partitioned.

Comment: @sawdust Should be compatible, I found one of the floppies labelled as a PXRD boot disk in the drive I'm using.

Comment: @Tetsujin Is was the companies tech that suggested I make the backup but I'll reach out to the main HQ. I don't really see the point since all the floppy does is run the half-million dollar (when new) instrument, not any value on it's own.

Comment: what did you use for dd because dd expects  dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=512  Where you substitute the correct designation for sda and sdb.  dd does not require you mount anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To be clear, my main question is "How do I mount this disk in such a way as to be able to cat or dd it? Is this a limitation of WSL or am I just mounting it wrong"?

That's something you typically do **without** mounting it. Tools such as 'dd' don't copy filesystems as file/folder structures – they copy the raw data blocks (sectors) found *underneath*. To do that, you need to give 'dd' the path to the device itself; typically `/dev/fd0` for floppy drives connected via the traditional Shugart interface or `/dev/sda` for USB floppy drives.

In other words, that's *not* something that you could possibly do through DrvFs or anything else that shares a filesystem. You need either to pass the raw disk to WSL2 somehow (which I believe was made sort of possible recently but not in a way that's useful to you), or – easier – use a native Windows version of `dd` that does the same through Windows-style device access.

[This dd.exe](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) is what was traditionally used, along with its GUI version [RawWrite](http://www.chrysocome.net/rawwrite) that was pretty much purpose-built to copy floppies. Be careful to not mix up the "read" and "write" ends; check the write-protect tab of the floppy disk just to be sure.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. The disk is write-protected, and I'm testing it on two other floppies first to make sure I have everything set up correctly. I'll try that tomorrow. If it doesn't work, I've already gotten an old computer with an IDE floppy drive instead of using a USB one.

Answer (score 2):

A floppy is just a file system on a disk at the end of the day.  Imaging programs used to be able to interact with them the same as an external drive.  I'd assume this functionality is still there, although I don't have a floppy drive to test.  But I'd assume if you can get your computer to recognize it and the disk imaging program still has support for floppy drives, you can take an image of the floppy, in which case you can probably write that image to any disk, another floppy or USB drive.  Of course, in theory.

Comment: yes this program is relevant to that. VFD for windows https://vfd.sourceforge.net/  And for linux ddrescue is always good for images.

Answer (score 0):

If your old computer has a CD Drive as well, then I would suggest, using a Live CD, like the ones mentioned below ( Open Source & Free ) ( they graphically show you the drives that are available on their Desktop, as icons ):

A 32-Bit Version ( i686 architecture ) : https://sourceforge.net/projects/live-cd-with-zerofree-32-bit/

For very OLD Architectures, Please try this Live CD : https://sourceforge.net/projects/live-cd-with-zerofree-x86/

A few hints, if your are new to using a Live CD:

Use a free image burning program, like imgburn (windows), brasero (linux), burn (macosx) etc. to burn this .iso file to a CD first and then restart the system and quickly change bios boot order, to start the system from this Live CD. Search and check youtube videos, if you are new to this concept of booting with Live CDs.

Hope this helps all.